# How can I link back to Bills and Adjustments for a record from the Approvals screen?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to add a non-bound (display only) field to the grid in the Approvals screen.  This field's value comes from a bound user field in an APInvoice DAC extension class.  My problem is that in the RowSelected event for the Approvals screen grid (which is the EPOwned DAC), I'm trying to link back to the Bills and Adjustments screen records via the RefNbr on the Approvals screen grid.

Although the Approvals grid shows it as the RefNbr, the actual field in the EPOwned DAC is a GUID.  By some magic (I've pored over the source code for this screen and I cannot find where it creates an APInvoiceEntry Graph to open that screen - even though it does, somehow), it knows to link the clicked-on record in the Approvals grid to the Bills and Adjustments RefNbr / record.

My hunch is that it all has some link with the RefNoteID / NoteID in EPOwned (EPApproval ) - but I cannot find any link between the EPOwned records and the APInvoice / APRegister records.

Does anyone know how to link, through BQL, the EPOwned (EPApproval) record and the APInvoice record that is related to the Refnbr shown in the Approvals grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, it is found that the EPOwned DAC (which contains EPApproval) is linked back to the APInvoice DAC via the following:

EPOwned.RefNoteID = APInvoice.NoteID

This will provide the necessary link to find the APInvoice.RefNbr